# XpathExpressrion; get value of timestamp

Tags: java, xpath, timestamp

I am trying to read the value of an attribute containing a timestamp from a node.
My xml looks like this

```
    <doc>
<str name="request_code">\</str>
<str name="id">3226</str>
<str name="request_name">John Doe</str>
<str name="type">Requests</str>
<str name="content_txt">...</str>
<str name="id">...</str>
<date name="lastModified_dt">1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
</doc>
```

I am able to get value of all the attributes except for the timestamp using 
the following expression,

```
.//str[@name='content_txt']
```

However when i try to get the value of the timestamp using the expression

```
.//date[@name='lastModified_dt']
```

It always returns empty.

Here is my Implementation

```
private Date getDateValue(Node responseNodeUrl, String attribute) throws SearchException {
        try {   
            Node evalNode = null;
            evalNode = responseNodeUrl;
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr;
             expr = xPath.compile(".//date[@name='"+attribute+"']");  
            Object result ;
            result= expr.evaluate(evalNode);    
            xPath.reset();
            System.out.println(result);

            return result;
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            log.error("Error in SearchEngine:getAttributeValue:: "+e.getMessage());
            throw new SearchException(e);
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.